# Decay of a convolution from its Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, quantum-field-theory

I have the following, physically motivated problem:

Consider the convolution $F(x):=\int f(y)\Delta_0(x-y)d^4y$ where $f\in\mathcal{C}_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^4)$, i.e. smooth and compactly supported, while $\Delta_0\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^4)$ is the **massless** two-point function (Wightman function). It can be written as

1. $\Delta_0(x)=\int\delta(k^2)\theta(k^0)e^{-ikx}d^4k$
2. $\Delta_0(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x^2-i\epsilon x^0}$

Theorem 4.1.1 in Hörmander's "The Analysis of partial differential operators I" asserts that $F\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^4)$. However, I would like to make some statements on the decay properties of $F$ (1. suggest that it decays like $1/r^2$ in spacelike directions).

More generally, how can I determine the decay properties of a function $f$ through its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$?

If $f$ was integrable I would try to use the connection $x_i f(x)\leftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial k_i}\hat{f}(k)$, but how can I proceed if $f$ is smooth but not integrable, e.g. a smooth (tempered) distribution?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: They should be alright now. Thanks

Comment: No. Please define it correctly. Is it the limit in the sense distribution of some sequence of functions ? Is it the Fourier transform of a given distribution ? What is it ? How do you know the Fourier transform has a simple expression ? Do you mean $|k|^2$ (the norm) ? What is $\delta(k^2)$ ? What is the domain of integration ? What is $k^0,x^0,\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: Yes, there was still a limit missing. The simple expression for the two-point function is from a textbook.

$k^2$ comes from the Lorentz "scalar product": $xy=x_0y_0-x_1y_1-x_2y_2-x_3y_3$, the domain of integration is $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: In $\Bbb{R}^4$, $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{|x|^2-i\epsilon x^0}  = \frac1{|x|^2} \in L^1([-R,R]^4)$ and the shape of  $\frac1{|x|^2}  \ast \phi$ is obvious. The Fourier transform of $\frac1{|x|^2}$ is $C \frac1{|k|^2}$

Comment: If you really mean $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x_0^2-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2-i\epsilon x_0} $ then it is another story.

Comment: For clarification: $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$

Comment: The connection/duality $x_i f(x)\leftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial k_i}\hat{f}(k)$ is still valid for distributions.

Comment: Is it? I am having some trouble using it since $\hat{f}(0)$ is not finite. Can you maybe explain a little more how it can be used?

Answer (score 1):

My idea for a solution:

Let $x=(x_0,\vec{x})\in\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\operatorname{supp} f\subset O$. Then

$\int f(y)\Delta_0(x-y)d^4x=\int_O f(y)\Delta_0(x-y)d^4x$.

I am interested in the behavior for fixed $x_0$ and $|\vec{x}|\rightarrow\infty$.

For $|\vec{x}|$ large enough, we leave $\operatorname{singsupp}\Delta_0=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^4:x^2=x_0^2-|\vec{x}|^2=0\}$ and we can treat $\Delta_0$ as a smooth function:

$\left|\int_O f(y)\Delta(x-y)d^4x\right|\leq\int_O\left|f(y)\Delta(x-y)\right|d^4x\leq\sup_{y\in O}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|^2-(x_0-y_0)^2}\int_O |f(y)|d^4y$

The asymptotic behavior is governed by the supremum term.